# Translate Wilson Score Confidence SQL Code to Codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, translation

I can't seem to translate the Wilson Score Confidence SQL code to Codeigniter active record code. Here is the ordinary SQL for the Wilson Score Confidence:

```
SELECT *, ((likes+ 1.9208) / (likes + dislikes) - 
                   1.96 * SQRT((likes * dislikes) / (likes + dislikes) + 0.9604) / 
                          (likes + dislikes)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (likes + dislikes)) 
       AS ci_lower_bound FROM widgets WHERE likes + dislikes > 0 
       ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC;
```

This was taken from: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Here was my attempted translation which didn't seem to work:

```
        $this->db->select('*, ((likes + 1.9208) / (likes + dislikes) - 1.96 * SQRT((likes * dislikes) / (likes + dislikes) + 0.9604) / (likes + dislikes)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (likes + dislikes)) AS ci_lower_bound');
        $this->db->where('likes + dislikes >', 0);
        $this->db->order_by("ci_lower_bound", "desc");
        $query = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(1)); 
        $data['results'] = $query->result();
```

The results always end up as empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... Turns out my code was right after all. There was just some glitch with MySQL:

```
$this->db->select('*, ((likes + 1.9208) / (likes + dislikes) - 1.96 * SQRT((likes * dislikes) / (likes + dislikes) + 0.9604) / (likes + dislikes)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (likes + dislikes)) AS ci_lower_bound');
$this->db->where('likes + dislikes >', 0);
$this->db->order_by("ci_lower_bound", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get('posts', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(1)); 
$data['results'] = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.the table name has not been specified in code "widgets"
try:
        $this->db->from('widgets');
```